# Downloading .xls throws error - File is not in specified format

Tags: javascript, php

As the title specifies, I get a File is not in specified format error when downloading the file. The following is my code. Also, the downloaded file does not have any cells.

```
    $content = ob_end_flush();
$filename = trim($filename);
$filename = str_replace(array(' ', '/', '\\'), '', $title);
$filename .= "_Export.xls";
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
//header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

put:

```
ob_clean();
ob_start();
```

before

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
```

and try...

---

**OR**

change

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
```

to

```
header('Content-type: application/msexcel; charset=utf-8');
```

or

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: yeah..its working..but it doesn't gives data into cell...means not getting rows and columns lines...

Comment: check if the page displays the content by commenting all the header methods...then try

Comment: Thank you sir....but still not getting cells...If i used ob_clean() then give cells but not gives data into it....